# UpdateProfilePhotoRequest не принимает InputPhoto

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

При попытке сменить фотографию профиля на фотографию профиля другого пользователя, выдает ошибку
**RPCError 400: PHOTO_ID_INVALID (caused by UpdateProfilePhotoRequest):**

```
p = client.get_profile_photos(user_0["username"])[0]

client(UpdateProfilePhotoRequest(
     id=types.InputPhoto(
         id=p.id,
         access_hash=p.access_hash,
         file_reference=p.file_reference
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что **UpdateProfilePhotoRequest** меняет аватарку на вашу старую загруженную фотографию в профиле

Для загрузки новой аватарки нужно использовать **UploadProfilePhotoRequest**